# Does AWS Client VPN Endpoint allow access to the client machine from a machine in the AWS VPN?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have successfully set up a Client VPN Endpoint connection on AWS for my local machine. I can access AWS VPN resources from my local machine, but I am wondering if I can establish the reverse as well: can I access my local machine from a virtual machine within my AWS VPN as well?

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing the answer is probably "yes". You should be able to verify that with a simple "ping" ;)

Comment: I did try a ping, but unfortunately it doesn't respond... thanks for the suggestion